# Reading data by kaggle

Tags: kaggle

Is there any way to use the Dataset which is on Kaggle - directly in 'Google Colab' or 'Our Local Machine' - without being externally downloaded manually?

For example, we have a dataset.
https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews?select=winemag-data-130k-v2.csv

if I want to read in Colab or Local machine something like this -

pd.read_csv('https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews?select=winemag-data-130k-v2.csv')

Is this is possible **or ** we need to manually download the dataset to use it?